# how do I express a Vaadin BeanItemContainer construtor in Scala?

Tags: scala, vaadin

I'm trying to load a bunch of com.mongodb.DBObject objects in to a Vaadin BeanItemContainer to display in a table.  I'm getting stuck on the translation of the constructor from Java to Scala.

The constructor definition is:

```
BeanItemContainer(Class<? extends BT> type)
```

This passes the scala compiler:

```
val bic = new BeanItemContainer(Class.forName("com.mongodb.DBObject"))
```

However, when I try to add an item:

```
mtl.toArray.foreach {t => bic.addBean(t)}
```

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]com/sentientswarm/traderdashboard/UploadTradesWindow.scala:140: error: type mismatch;
 found   : t.type (with underlying type com.mongodb.DBObject)
 required: ?0 where type ?0
            mtl.toArray.foreach {t => bic.addBean(t)}
```

Any thoughts/suggestions?

UPDATE:
Tried:

```
val bic: BeanItemContainer[DBObject] = new BeanItemContainer(Class.forName("com.mongodb.DBObject"))
```

Result:

```
[ERROR]com/sentientswarm/traderdashboard/UploadTradesWindow.scala:140: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.Class[?0(in value bic)] where type ?0(in value bic)
 required: java.lang.Class[_ <: com.mongodb.DBObject]
            val bic: BeanItemContainer[DBObject] = new BeanItemContainer(Class.forName("com.mongodb.DBObject"))
                                                                                      ^
```

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you're using `Class.forName`? I don't think the compiler can infer the type from the returned object from that call, it would just be `Class[_]`. If you use `classOf`, it should let the compiler determine the type:

```
val bic = new BeanItemContainer[DBObject](classOf[DBObject]))
```

In other words: `DBObject.class` in Java translates to `classOf[DBObject]` in Scala.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about classOf.  I arrived at the same conclusion, but a little simpler.  You can just use: val bic = new BeanItemContainer(classOf[DBObject]).  That said, DBObject doesn't like being told it's a bean, so I ended up using an IndexedContainer and populating it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val bic: BeanItemContainer[BT] = new BeanItemContainer(Class.forName("com.mongodb.DBObject"))
```

By the way, you removed the "^" marker of where in the line the error is. Please, keep it when pasting error messages.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the carat.  Thought I got it.  The code you suggested throws an error too.  I've updated the main question with the error since I don't think I can format here.